# All (GeoTIFF) raster values NA after converting to velox

Tags: r, geotiff-tiff, extract

Cross-posted to the velox GitHub repo:  https://github.com/hunzikp/velox/issues/40

---

I'm able to extract average tree cover values for each of the three small counties in the US State of Delaware, but I don't seem to have enough CPU or RAM to do the same thing for all counties in the US.

*I'm getting my tree cover data from https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/StagedProducts/Small-scale/data/LandCover/tree48i0100a.tif_nt00840.tar.gz.  See also https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/581d0548e4b08da350d52653*

```
library(raster)
library(tigris)

tigris.state.counties <- counties(state = 10)
tree.raster <-
  raster("tree48i0100a.tif")

polygon.trees <-
  extract(tree.raster,
          tigris.state.counties,
          fun = mean,
          na.rm = TRUE)

report <-
  cbind.data.frame(tigris.state.counties$NAME, polygon.trees)

print(report)

  tigris.state.counties$NAME polygon.trees
1                 New Castle      70.75920
2                     Sussex      68.17089
3                       Kent      67.00225
```

So I have set up an R environment on a 64 GB AWS instance, and I'm trying to take advantage of the `velox` fast extraction.  But all of the values I extract are `NA`.

**What am I doing wrong?**

***UPDATE:  I still get NAs even if I use the [small polygon option](http://philipphunziker.com/velox/extract.html#the_small_option)***

*FWIW, I was able to replicate the [velox extract tutorial](http://philipphunziker.com/velox/extract.html) and even modify it to get the night light intensity in the Delaware counties.*

**My attempt to extract tree cover in Delaware counties with velox:**

```
library(velox)
library(tigris)

tree.velox <- velox("tree48i0100a.tif")

tigris.state.counties <- counties(state = 10)

tree.mean.mat <-
  tree.velox$extract(
    sp = tigris.state.counties,
    fun = function(x)
      mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  )

report <-
  cbind.data.frame(tigris.state.counties$NAME, tree.mean.mat)

print(report)

     tigris.state.counties$NAME tree.mean.mat
591                  New Castle            NA
1150                     Sussex            NA
2861                       Kent            NA
```